# Como restringir acesso a uma determinada pagina no painel adm. do wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Dentro do painel administrativo do *wordpress*, preciso criar cerca de 10 paginas, onde cada usuário tenha acesso apenas à pagina que corresponde a ele.

Exemplo:

**Usuário X teria acesso apenas ao painel administrativo da pagina X e
usuário Y teria acesso apenas ao painel administrativo da pagina Y.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Até onde sei o *wordpress* não disponibiliza algo do tipo como *default*.
Tentei utilizar alguns *plug-ins* como o [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) e o [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/), porém em ambos o bloqueio é feito apenas para o *post-type* "paginas" ou seja apenas bloqueiam o acesso de todas as paginas ocultando o campo paginas do menu esquerdo para os usuários bloqueados, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Painel do adminimize - campo "paginas" ao lado no menu esquerdo some para os usuários bloqueados.*

---

Leve em consideração as seguintes perguntas:

- Como posso criar um controle parecido com esse do *adminimize* porém liberando apenas uma pagina para cada usuário (como o exemplo da primeira imagem)?
- Como posso criar outros tipos de usuários alem dos default do wordpress (admin, editor, assinante...)?

*OBS.: Não há nenhum problema se a solução proposta tiver que usar "post" ao invés de "paginas".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como posso criar um controle parecido com esse do adminimize porém liberando apenas uma pagina para cada usuário (como o exemplo da primeira imagem)?

Aconselho você usar um plugin pra fazer isso. Fazer na mão vai dar bastante trabalho. O [Role Scoper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) permite que você de permissões para páginas de acordo com o papel (role) do usuário. Ele cria varios campos onde você seleciona usuários ou grupo de usuários que podem ler e/ou editar os posts/páginas.

Existe também o [User Specific Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content/screenshots/), que é voltado mais para conteúdo do que para posts e páginas propriamente ditas. Esse talvez não responda a sua pergunta, mas é sempre bom saber que existe.

> Como posso criar outros tipos de usuários alem dos default do wordpress (admin, editor, assinante...)?

Com o método [`add_role()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role). Da própria documentação

```
$result = add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```

Cria o *role* **Basic Contributor**, que tem um certo número de permissões e capacidades. Você pode ver os diversos *roles* [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles).

Se você colocar esse método direto no `functions.php`, por exemplo, do jeito que ele está ali, você pode ter problemas, pois esse código vai rodar sempre. A documentação sugere (e eu também) que você crie um plugin, que crie o *role* uma vez, apenas quando o plugin for iniciado. Pra isso você usa o *hook* [Register Activation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)